# Unable to cover apex Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Apex Class

```
 public class get_data{
 public static map<string,map<String,String>> get_tier(String fetchFrom){
        map<string,map<String,String>> dataFields = new map<string,map<String,String>>();
        String bankerType = [select id,Contact.AccountId,Contact.Account.banker_Type__c from user where id=:userinfo.getUserId()].Contact.Account.banker_Type__c;

        IF((fetchFrom==NULL || fetchFrom=='') && bankerType == 'Banker1'){
            fetchFrom = 'Bank1__mdt'; //unable to cover this line
        }
        ELSE IF((fetchFrom==NULL || fetchFrom=='') && bankerType == 'Banker2'){
            fetchFrom = 'Bank2__mdt';
        }
        ELSE IF((fetchFrom==NULL || fetchFrom=='') && bankerType == 'Banker3'){
            fetchFrom = 'Bank3__mdt';
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class get_dataTest {

    @isTest static void test(){                                
         Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='system admin'];
        UserRole UR=[Select Id from UserRole where Name='system admin'];        
        String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
        Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
        String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;        
        User u = [SELECT id from User where ContactId =: System.Label.Con_Id];      
        Contact c = [SELECT id, AccountId from Contact where Id =: System.Label.Con_Id ];       
        system.runAs(u){
            Test.startTest();
            Account acc = new Account(
                Name='acc',
                Banker_Type__c ='Banker1'        
            );
            Insert acc;
            Contact con = new Contact(
                LastName='LastName', 
                AccountId = acc.Id);
            insert con;     
        Test.startTest();    
        get_data.get_tier('');
        Test.startTest();
    }
}
```

My test class is not going inside if condition, although I am passing that info. I am missing something here can some one help me with this test class, thanks.

/****working code*****/

```
@isTest
public with sharing class get_dataTest {

    @isTest static void test(){                                
         Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='system admin'];
         Account acc = new Account(
                Name='acc',
                Banker_Type__c ='Banker1'        
            );
            Insert acc;
            Contact con = new Contact(
                LastName='LastName', 
                AccountId = acc.Id);
            insert con;        
            User u = new User(Alias = 'standt1',Country='United 
            Kingdom',Email='demo1@domain.com',EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', 
                          LastName='Testing989', 
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',LocaleSidKey='en_US',ProfileId = 
            p.Id,TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', 
                          UserName='dpr9891@camfed.org',ContactId = con.Id );      

        system.runAs(u){

        Test.startTest();    
        get_data.get_tier('');
        Test.startTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Custom Metadata does not seem to have *anything* to do with this post.

Comment: It seems like your User is not connected with Contact. You can confirm that by using system.debug('Banker Type::' + bankerType) after your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of questionable code in your test class, but to answer your immediate question:

When the query in get_data.get_tier runs, it's looking at the Contact associated with the running user.  The problem is, the ContactId of the User in your runAs statement *isn't* the Contact you've inserted in your test class. Since its Banker_Type__c value isn't "Banker1," the first conditional is never true.

I think you could get a lot out of looking over some resources that cover writing unit tests in Apex.  We all started in Salesforce development somewhere...and this is where I started when I learned to write unit tests!

> https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests
>
> https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Shane, you were right my user was not linked with contact. I have updated my code in the question, thank you!